# Login/Logout button in header for wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication

In my [Wordpress site](https://suonareaorecchio.com), I have a Login/Logout button in the top right header (In Italian it'd be Accedi/Esci), created with this code:

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_login_logout_link', 10, 2);
function add_login_logout_link($items, $args) {
    ob_start();
    wp_loginout('index.php');
    $loginoutlink = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    $items .= '<li>'. $loginoutlink .'</li>';
return $items;
}
```

The Login URL that it creates after clicking is:

> /wp-login.php?redirect_to=index.php

Since I have a membership plugin, I need to keep its redirect-after-login rule (a specific page I chose, let's say "Login welcome page"), and for that to be working, I need to keep:

> /wp-login.php

I tried to delete `wp_loginout('index.php');` but the "Login/logout" button will disappear from header.

After logout this code take me to the home (that's what I want!) but if I take only the "index.php" off, there's no redirectio after logout.

Do you know how can I fix that?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What I propose is to set the current URL segment, eg, `news/1` to `$_SESSION` or `$_COOKIE` when user clicks the logout button and after the logout redirect to the saved value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to redirect the user to the current page they were on:

`wp_loginout( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );`

If you want to direct them to a specific page, you can change the $redirect param to point to whatever page you want.  You can use `get_permalink( $post_id )` for front-end pages.

`wp_loginout( get_permalink( $post_id ) );`

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_loginout
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink

***Redirect to different page on login vs logout*** 
Just wrap in a `is_user_logged_in()` conditional.  Will look like:

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    wp_loginout( Go Here if logged in );
} else {
    wp_loginout( Go here if logged out );
}
```

Comment: That was fantastic Dsmart. It worked perfectly. Thanks a lot.I choose `wp_loginout( get_permalink( get_page_by_title( 'La mia pagina' ) ) );` so they're redirect to a specific page. Is there a way to redirect the logout to the home page (while keeping the login as above of course)

Comment: Sure, you just need to wrap it in a conditional.  I've updated my answer above.  Would you mind marking as correct?

Comment: Thanks for replying mate. I'm not sure where and how to add this line. Starting from `add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_login_logout_link', 10, 2);
function add_login_logout_link($items, $args) {
        ob_start();
        wp_loginout( get_permalink( get_page_by_title( 'La mia pagina' ) ) );
        $loginoutlink = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        $items .= '<li>'. $loginoutlink .'</li>';
    return $items;
}` when I try to wrap the `is_user_logged_in()` my website says "unexpected error in functions.php". would you mind show me how the how the full code will be? Thanks!